# Strip all domains except one from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I got string like 'facebook.com somenickname google.com example.com'. I mean there's a string that can contain multiple urls and my domain - example.com. I want to strip all the urls from that string except "example.com", so output would be like " somenickname  example.com"

I tried to use the following regex, but don't know how to exclude my domain.

```js
string.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\/?/i, '').trim()
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead with word boundary for this task.

```js
var re = /\b(?!example\.com)(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\/?\b/g;
var str = 'facebook.com somenickname google.com example.com';
console.log(str.replace(re, '')); // replace matches
console.log(str.replace(re, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ')); // also replace space chars
```

- Negative Lookahead `(?!example\.com)`. Assert that the Regex below does not match

  - `example` matches the characters `example` literally (case sensitive)
  - `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)
  - `com` matches the characters `com` literally (case sensitive)